# Create a SQL database in Azure Portal let you select a collation. How to retrieve this list externally?

Tags: sql, json, azure-devops, collation, azureportal

When we create a SQL database on the Azure Portal, the portal give the possibility to select the collation you want from a list:

[image]

I would like to integrate this list in my own azure devops extension, inside the task.json.
I know set dataSourceBindings, query and filter REST Api.

Here, my problem is to find the source of this collection list, where it is stored ?

Does anybody can help me to find the way ?

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server you can execute these selects to get all collations:

These are Windows related: `SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations() WHERE name NOT LIKE 'SQL%'`

These are SQL Server related: `SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations() WHERE name LIKE 'SQL%'`

Cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/sql-server-collation-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

With this you can have a fixed list in your `json` file and don't need to query this list all over again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My goal is to limit the use of fixed list that I have to maintain and keep my code clean without to have a very long fixed list which pollute the code. I'm trying to find an elegant way, and this list from MS sound a good way to reach the goal.